# What revision of C is targeted by ROS 2?

Tags: ros, ros2, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP-2000](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html)  is stating that ROS 2 is targeting C++14. What about C? Is it a safe assume that all packages are compiled against C11?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315686/what-revision-of-c-is-targeted-by-ros-2?/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2019-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, we use / need C11. I updated the REP accordingly: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/189

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-02-14**:
Windows doesn't implement C11 (and I don't think they intend to do so).

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2019-02-14**:
Awesome! Indeed the reason I was asking this is due to Windows related build issues.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-02-14**:
@Thomas I'd be interested to know what issues you've been having, since I've dealt with a few over the past few years related to C11 and Windows.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2019-02-15**:
@William the PR is here: https://github.com/ros2/rcl/pull/332 (strncpy_s / strncpy incompatibility) - seems like we finally went with memcopy.